# PHP put Numbers into Order highest to lowest?

Tags: javascript, php, list, sorting

So my Php gets Javascript vars and then sends them to a file called LeaderBoard.txt
What I want the Php to do is when it sends the information to the .txt file I want it so the scores are sorted from highest to lowest...

so if in the .txt file there is

1. score: 5
2. score: 3

and the score that is being posted is "score: 4" I want the php to put it in this posistion:

1. score: 5
2. score: 4
3. score: 3

Iv no idea how to do it so how could i do it?
and how can i implement it into my existing code?
Thanks for reading :) and heres my php so far:

```
<?php 

$hiScore = $_POST['hiScore'] ? $_POST['hiScore'] : 'not set';

$theInput = $_POST['theInput'] ? $_POST['theInput'] : 'not set';

$file = fopen('LeaderBoard.txt','a+');
fwrite($file, ' Name: '.$theInput.'                                        Score: '.$hiScore.'                         '.PHP_EOL);
fclose($file);


?>
```

I'm a really newby with php and its a stuggle so sorry if this seems a silly question

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're saving this information to a text file instead of to a database table?

Comment: Please check out the docs on [sorting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) and try to implement them.  Then if you still have questions, ask again.

Comment: If you want to store this on a file, it should at least be either an `xml` or a `json`. Try `JSON` better since it works wonders with `AJAX`, but not a `.txt`

Comment: Couldn't natsort() or natcasesort() be used with .txt?

Comment: @–  dg99 I've read it Im still not sure on how to put the input from the js vars into an array any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it like this:

```
<?php 

$hiScore = $_POST['hiScore'] ? $_POST['hiScore'] : 'not set';

$theInput = $_POST['theInput'] ? $_POST['theInput'] : 'not set';

$file = fopen('LeaderBoard.txt','a+');
fwrite($file, ' '.$hiScore.' - Score                                                      Name: '.$theInput.'      '.PHP_EOL);
fclose($file);

$lines = file("LeaderBoard.txt");
natsort($lines);
$lines=array_reverse($lines);
file_put_contents("LeaderBoardScores.txt", implode("\n  \n", $lines));
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `ksort` ...
ksort is used to sort an array element from lowest to highest. You can use other sorting functions in php through the below link.
[enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)

Comment: `ksort` sorts by keys. Kinda useless when you don't even have an array to sort yet in the OP's code.